# javascript syntax string operators

Tags: javascript, html

help me out guys, i dont seem to know why the error is popping up. (i started learning javacript and i'm testing out how a string operator looks like)

```html
<html>
      <head><title>Head</title></head>
      <body></body>
    
    <script>
    var age=27;
    var info = "my name is Daniel, i am " +age + " years old " + 10;
    console.log(info);
    </script>
    
    </html>
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' debugger eval code:1

Comment: it works fine , but if you want to add `10` to age you must be doing this instead `var info = "my name is Daniel, i am " + (age+10) + " years old ";`

Comment: It is working fine. try pressing ctrl+shift+r

Comment: I am unable to replicate the error. Is there something else in the code? Also, try putting the script tag in the body to see if it helps

Comment: Are you putting everything in .js file?

Comment: Perhaps the author has put the posted code into a .js file. If this is the case, either change the file extension to .html to open it in the browser OR remove all HTML tags (and keep the .js file extension) and link it from another HTML page with a script tag (external script) or run it in Node.

Comment: How did you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

add script inside this BODY tag, and You can code like this

```
    <html>
      <head><title>Head</title></head>
      <body>
      <script>
          var age=27;
       // var info = "my name is Daniel, i am " +age + " years old " + 10;
          var info = `my name is Daniel, i am ${age} years old 10`;
        console.log(info);
      </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i tried and i am still getting an error. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The error is a JS error, not an HTML. If you put everything in JS(including HTML too) you probably get this error.

1. Either create two seperate files(.JS and .HTML) and put reference of .js in HTML
2. Put everything in HTML.

### 1. Two Files(JS and HTML)

```js
 var age = 27;
 var info = "my name is Daniel, i am " + age + " years old " + 10;
 console.log(info);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Head</title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

### 2. Single HTML file

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Head</title>

</head>

<body></body>
<script>
    var age = 27;
    var info = "my name is Daniel, i am " + age + " years old " + 10;
    console.log(info);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks guys. The problem was from my editor. the problem was automatically fixed after i updated the code editor.